# Absolute positioned div looks different... in different instances of the same browser

Tags: css, html, positioning

This is a bizarre issue I'm having - I have positioned a div absolutely in pixels, and it looks great in Google Chrome while I'm working on the site. However, the div is thrown off in every other window I view it in, including when I open up the site in Google Chrome Incognito mode. I thought it might be an issue with the cache, but this deviation persists even after I emptied it. I'm just completely befuddled. Why does it only look right in that one instance?

This is a screenshot of the two windows placed side by side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoYuk.jpg (Normal viewing mode on the left, Incognito on the right).

This is the code, it's the most basic it can get:

```
#magic-book {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 89px;
}
```

The site in question is www.charlotteenglish.com/home

In this case the position is fairly important because it affects the legibility of some text. I am using Wordpress, but I disabled the admin toolbar that normally appears at the top of the page. Could it do with me being logged into Wordpress? I can't think of why that'd affect it.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: OK, it's not the div that is different in different windows - it's the entire site. I suppose that changes the question slightly, but the underlying issue still remains. Here's another screenshot to demonstrate: [http://imgur.com/8bPyAfE](https://imgur.com/8bPyAfE)

Comment: Actually it is perfect in Chrome. Where is the first issue coming in? Which browser and version? Yup... I viewed in both Normal and Incognito. Should be a **cache** issue. Press Ctrl + Shift + R and let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply! The positioning is still off after doing Ctrl + Shift + R - when you view it is the black bar lined up with the text on the menu? I also noticed that it's actually not the div that is changing, but the position of the site itself... I'm on Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Comment: But I have seen in both the normal and incognito mode. They look the same. So, should be an issue with the CSS caching. Try clearing the cache and check na?

Comment: It must be the CSS cache, yeah. I inspected the CSS and the Incognito shows old code - but even emptying the cache (both on the site and in my browser), restarting, refreshing many times... it won't go away. Quite frustrating! I'm going to wait for the cache to expire... but good to hear others aren't seeing this problem.

Comment: Nice. :) So hopefully problem is solved. Lemme check some best ways to clear cache in Chrome and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is perfect in Chrome. Where is the first issue coming in? Which browser and version? Yup... I viewed in both Normal and Incognito. Should be a **cache** issue.

1. Click the **Chrome menu** on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Tools**.
3. Select **Clear browsing data**.
4. In the dialogue that appears, select the tickboxes for the types of information that you want to remove.
5. Use the menu at the top to select the amount of data that you want to delete. Select **beginning of time** to delete everything.
6. Click **Clear browsing data**.